# Single password versus password and username

Tags: authentication

What security benefits password and username provides over just single password as login?

If username must be unique, then other users cannot have that username and user can be mapped to user account with that id. When attacker brute forces against username and password, it same as attacker would brute force against single password. But with single password attacker can try to access all accounts with same password brute forcing.

After you are logged to application, you session is authenticated with single password, which is session id. So attacker could try to login to all accounts by bruteforcing session ids. Of course session ids are usually very long and therefor very hard to bruteforce.

What if application generates automatically password tokens and adds always unique prefix (length of prefix is stored in database) for passwords that what is mapped to specific user. So that password is actually combination of username and password, but user doesn't know that? Will that kind of setup have same security as username and password system?

Comment: I would vote to migrate this to security.stackexchange.com where it's likely to get a better answer - but there doesn't seem to be an option for that. (You might consider asking it there though :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When thinking about a single password approach I can see a number of possible issues, for instance if you are allowing users to set their own passwords then just having password as login credentials opens up your application to massive security flaws.

The most common scenario is that a user will sign up and use a password such as their name, or some other commonly used insecure password thus making it easy to brute force.

Also consider the fact that as the number of users grows the number of acceptable passwords to access your site also grows which makes it easier for brute force attacks to work. Even with auto generated passwords this is the largest issue I would be concerned with.

Thirdly, I come along and try sign up to your site, I type in my password "Bob1"  now what if another user has entered the password "Bob1" ? Do you inform me that password exists? Two users cant log into distinct accounts with the same password.

The main issue here to consider though is that users are used to typing a username and password. I personally wouldnt want to sign up to a website where I just have to type in a password, and most importantly I wouldnt want to use a web site where my password is auto generated and hard to remember.

If you are concerned about security (as you should be) then I suggest enforcing strict password rules (expiry time, length, content) and educating your users about the flaws of insecure passwords. On creation of the password you can check it doesnt match any info the user has entered such as name/ date of birth etc.

Overall I would say username / password combo is better than single password for both security and usability reasons.
Also see http://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 0):

If you use only password, then someone could type a word like 'helloworld' and log in to a random account. 
Coz there would be someone who is using this password.

There are many who would use familiar phrase as password. Its users convinence.

Such type of loophole dosent exist in username-password combination.